# To disable scrolling in TabLayout fragment in CollapsingToolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a screen with CollapsingToolbar and below I have a TabLayout with some fragments.

One such fragment has data retrieved with RecyclerView.

The problem is when the screen shrinks the fragment that has the RecyclerView scrolls together and delays the CollapsingToolbar, giving an unwanted effect.

Is there any way I can block the Scroll of the fragment until CollapsingToolbar finishes the process and collapses completely?

[Link Gif Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dco14okvfomexti/videotogif_2017.08.23_00.02.43.gif?dl=0)

Code Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/cinzaMEdio"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="170dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="10dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            >


            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="225dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/hair"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:cropToPadding="false"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="225dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg">

                </FrameLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvPerEmpNome"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
                    android:text="Firma X"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvNomeCidade"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:text="São Paulo - SP"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
            </FrameLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/ripple_menus_perfil_empresa">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_person_add"
                            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:cropToPadding="false"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:text="Seguir"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/ripple_menus_perfil_empresa">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_star_half"
                            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:cropToPadding="false"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:text="Avaliações"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/ripple_menus_perfil_empresa">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_photo"
                            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:cropToPadding="false"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:text="Fotos"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/ripple_menus_perfil_empresa">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_business"
                            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:cropToPadding="false"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:text="Sobre"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Agendar"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:background="@drawable/ripple_button_border_black"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Mensagem"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ripple_button_black"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarPerfilEmpresa"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                android:background="@color/cinza300"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs_perf_emp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/cinzaMEdio"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText">

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollViewContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffff0d02"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager_tabs_perf_emp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:minHeight="600dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/cinza300"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Code Fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cardFeedUser_list" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution. Removed NestedScrollView

```
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager_tabs_perf_emp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="600dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/cinza300"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use **`setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`** for `cardFeedUser_list` `recyclerView`

If you are using **API > 21**

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)
```

If you are using **API < 21**

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, true);
```

Comment: Did not work. When you add this attribute in CardView, when you open the activity and nothing slides anymore. @AyushKhare

Comment: @TiagoIB You need to add in your recyclerView and not in cardView

Comment: It worked, now it has no scrolling while CollapsingToolbar is rolling. But Recyclerview and Cardview also do not have the scrolling anymore, getting static content. @AyushKhare

Answer (score 0):

for the support library, you can easily control your app bar visibility.

```
setExpanded(true,true);
```

or

```
setExpanded(false,true);
```

Also, you can use DragCallback Method

```
private void setDragCallback() {
setDragCallback(new DragCallback() {
    @Override
    public boolean canDrag(@NonNull AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
        return mEnabled;
    }
});
```

}

Comment: I do not quite understand how I apply this to my activity. @HarshitTrivedi